# Can I import my Local Park into Facebook?

Tags: dragonvale

Imagine my surprise when I find out that Dragonvale is on Android now, in addition to iOS. So, to see what all the craze is about, I decide to get into it. I don't really have a Facebook, so I just bypassed all that. However, this locks me out of all the social stuff, including free Gems. This is, obviously, Not Ideal, so I made a Facebook account basically just for Dragonvale. Seems simple enough.

Too bad that, apparently, my Local Park isn't my Facebook Park! Is there a way to force my Local Park to be my Facebook Park? Or am I screwed unless I want to start over, which I'd *really* rather not do?

Comment: I haven't found a method to do this yet. I tried giving iOS Dragonvale access to facebook with no avail. There might be some greater trick to it though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Backflip has instructions for this in their [Android FAQ](http://www.backflipstudios.com/help/androidfaq/).

> DragonVale park progress is stored on our servers for Android devices when the park is associated with a Facebook account.  If you would like to associate your Local park with your Facebook account, please follow these steps (please note that this is a permanent choice and once you associate your Local park to your Facebook account, this cannot be undone):
>
> 1. Launch DragonVale
> 2. After DragonVale has loaded, tap on Options at the bottom of the screen
> 3. In the Options menu, tap on Login with the Facebook icon at the bottom. You will be directed to log into Facebook
> 4. You will receive a prompt asking if you want to continue playing your Local park or Facebook, select Facebook. Your Local park should now be associated with your Facebook account
> 5. If you receive an additional prompt after selecting Facebook, you likely will want to pick the higher level park (this will only happen if you have played DragonVale with your Facebook account in the past)
>
> Please note that you must log into Facebook to access your saved park if for some reason you do not remain logged into Facebook in DragonVale.

Comment: Hey there, and welcome to Arqade! Could you summarise the information in your link as part of your answer?

Comment: That does help, thank you very much! Though, as explained by Yves, could you copy and paste or summarize the relevant information in your answer, just in case the FAQ changes or goes away, or is inaccessible for some other reason? We call that "link rot" around here and we like to try to prevent it. :)