# Is there anyway in dragonvale to transfer your facebook save to local?

Tags: dragonvale

Is there any possible way AT ALL to transfer your dragonvale park to a local save data? (on the android tablet)

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunately, no.

While it is possible on Android to [transfer your local park to Facebook](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97649/can-i-force-my-local-park-onto-facebook), the reverse is not possible.

Note that if you choose to migrate your local save to Facebook, the process is not reversible, per the Backflip FAQ:

> Please note that this is a permanent choice and once you associate your Local park to your Facebook account, this cannot be undone

BackFlip FAQ on saving progress:

> **How do I save my game progress?**
>
> To save DragonVale park progress while using an Android device, you will need to use a Facebook account.